# Disable button when clicked in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to disable a button on click in React JS, as its function is to add articles to an array. When as user clicks saves article, the button should disable, so they can't save again.

So far for this component my code is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './news-hero.css';
import Carousel from "react-multi-carousel";
import "react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css";

const responsive = {
    superLargeDesktop: {
        breakpoint: { max: 4000, min: 3000 },
        items: 1,
    },
    desktop: {
        breakpoint: { max: 3000, min: 1024 },
        items: 1,
    },
    tablet: {
        breakpoint: { max: 1024, min: 464 },
        items: 1,
    },
    mobile: {
        breakpoint: { max: 464, min: 0 },
        items: 1,
    },
};

class NewsHero extends Component {
    _isMounted = false;
    state = {
        loading: false,
        data: [],
        headline: [],
        saved: []
    }

    saved = headline => {
        this.setState(
            (prevState) => ({ saved: [...prevState.saved, headline] }),
            () => {
                console.log('Saved articles = ', this.state.saved);
                alert('Article saved');
                localStorage.setItem('saved', JSON.stringify(this.state.saved));
                localStorage.getItem('saved');
            });
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.saved = this.saved.bind(this)
    }

    onError() {
        this.setState({
            imageUrl: "../assets/img-error.jpg"
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
        this.setState({ loading: true, saved: localStorage.getItem('saved') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('saved')) : [] })
        fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=timbaland&domains=rollingstone.com,billboard.com&excludeDomains=townsquare.media&apiKey=xxxx')
            .then(headline => headline.json())
            .then(headline => this.setState({ headline: headline.articles, loading: false }, () => console.log(headline.articles)))
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="hero">
                <h2 className="text-left">News</h2>

                {this.state.loading
                    ? "loading..."
                    : <div>
                        <Carousel
                            additionalTransfrom={0}
                            showDots={true}
                            arrows={true}
                            autoPlaySpeed={3000}
                            autoPlay={false}
                            centerMode={false}
                            className="carousel-hero"
                            containerClass="container-with-dots"
                            dotListClass="dots"
                            draggable
                            focusOnSelect={false}
                            infinite
                            itemClass="carousel-top"
                            keyBoardControl
                            minimumTouchDrag={80}
                            renderButtonGroupOutside={false}
                            renderDotsOutside
                            responsive={responsive}>
                            {this.state.headline.map((post, indx) => {
                                return (
                                    <div className="text-left mt-5" key={indx}>
                                        <img className="media-img card-img-top card-img-hero" src={post.urlToImage} alt="Alt text"></img>
                                        <div className="card-body container hero-text-body">
                                            <h1 className="card-title hero-title text-truncate">{post.title}</h1>
                                            <button className="btn-primary btn mt-2 mb-4" onClick={() => this.saved(post)}>Save article</button>
                                            <p className="card-text">{post.description}</p>
                                            <a href={post.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Read More</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })}
                        </Carousel>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default NewsHero;
```

Other questions answers don't really answer this straight question as the other questions are bespoke answers to other scenario codes.

Comment: Add a disabled prop to your button and save some state that determines if the button is disabled or not. Then set that state on click.

Comment: ok... do you have a code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the event to your `onClick()` function.

```
onClick={(e) => this.saved(e, post)}
```

You can then use that event and `currentTarget` to get the HTML element that contains the `onClick` and disable that element.

```
saved = (e, headline) => {
    // Disable clicked button
    e.currentTarget.disabled = true;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Ed Lucas suggest, you can do it like that or, you can maintain your button status on the state and change it according to click event.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      btnStatus: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button 
          disabled={this.state.btnStatus}
          onClick={() => this.setState({ btnStatus: true })}
        >
          CLICK
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```