# How to disable a button after it gets pressed? React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

How can I disable a button after it gets pressed once in a functional component??

Here's my code:

```
 const Verify = () => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
      .then(() => {
        Alert.alert(
            'Code Sent')
      });
  };

 <Button onPress={() => Verify();} />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable button when clicked in React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60471476/disable-button-when-clicked-in-react-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the prop `disabled` as mentioned in the docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/button#disabled)

```
const [isDisabled, setDisabled] = useState(false)
<Button onPress={() => Verify();} disabled={isDisabled} />
```

In your **Verify** function, you can set the `isDisabled` as true

```
setDisabled(true)
```